# Deserialization of JSON in swift 5 with JSONSerialization.jsonObject

Tags: json, macos, serialization

I'm trying to deserialize a json object in swift.  The JSON looks like this:

```
let data = """
{
    "code": 200,
    "message": "OK",
    "results": [
        { "id": 111, "name": "Tony"},
        { "id": 112, "name": "Bill"},
        { "id": 112, "name": "John"}

    ]
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!
```

I'm using this to deserialize the JSON

```
    var json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any]

print (json!["code"]!)
print (json!["message"]!)
print (json!["results"]!)
```

The correct values are printed in each case, but I can not figure out how to iterate across the value returned by

```
json!["reults"]
```

The error message is:

```
Type 'Any' does not conform to protocol 'Sequence'
```

Added- after first answer

First answer solves this problem.  However, I'm following code from Apple Deveoper's site they do this:

```
let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any] {
                for case let result in json["results"] {
                    if let restaurant = Restaurant(json: result) {
                        restaurants.append(restaurant)
                    }
                }
```

And the result they pass in  is a String,  is this just an old example?  Can I continue down this path?

Answer (score 1):

You have to downcast the value of `results` to an array (`[]`) of dictionaries (`{}`). Then iterate the array

```
let results = json!["results"] as! [[String:Any]]
for item in results {
    print(item["name"] as! String, item["id"] as! Int)
}
```

Side note: In Swift 4+ the `Codable` protocol is the better choice

Answer (score 1):

```
let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any] ?? [:]
if let dictJson = json { //If json is not nil
    if let arrResults = dictJson["results"] as? Array<Dictionary<String,Any>>{ //If results is not nil
        for result in arrResults {
            print(result) //Prints result
        }
    }
}
```

Try this. It will iterate result.